# QueryString parsing in Play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have nested url parameters being passed to an endpoint, and I need these represented in as a JsValue. My initial assumption was that Play would parse them in a way similar to Rails, however parameters seem to only be split by `&` and `=`. Example:

Query params: `?test[testkey]=testvalue&test[newkey]=newvalue`

Actual:

`Map(
  "test[testkey]" -> "testvalue" ,
  "test[newkey]"  -> "newvalue
)`

Expected:

`Map(
  "test" -> Map(
    "testkey" -> "testvalue" ,
    "newkey"  -> "newvalue"
  )
)`

Note that the end goal here is to be able to convert this into a JsObject.

I've started writing this myself, however simply porting the function from Rack is very un-scala-y and I feel like there has to be a quick way to get this that I am simply missing.

**UPDATE**

I am trying to find a generic solution which mimics the parsing that Rails uses (ie, with nested objects, lists, etc), and not just one level deep objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, one option is to do something like:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex
val pattern = new Regex("""(\w+)\[(\w+)\]""")

val qs : Map[String, Map[String, List[Seq[String]]]] = request.queryString.toList.map {
  case (k, v) =>
    pattern findFirstIn k match {
      case Some(pattern(key, value)) => (key, value, v)
    }
}.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(value => value.groupBy(_._2).mapValues {
  value => value.map(x => x._3)
})
```

To convert this is to a JsValue, we can simply invoke:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
Json.toJson(qs)
```

This assumes that all your url params look like `map[key]=value`. You would have to modify the code a little to accommodate the standard `key=value` pattern.

Comment: I also don't think this would work for nested arrays, such as `array[]=6&array[]=7`, or nested objects, such as `test[a][b]=7`. Or am I incorrect?

Comment: You are correct. However, it will work for multimaps; so map[key]=6&map[key]=7 would resolve into a list. For the other cases, you will have to play with the regex.